# CakePHP command line doesn't work when xdebug loaded

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, xdebug, intl

I'm trying to use xdebug against PHP 7.1.6 to troubleshoot a failing unit test in my CakePHP v3.3.6 project. I've set up xdebug using the following settings:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level=256
```

PHP now connects to my xdebug client (VisualStudio Code) but as soon as I run phpunit `./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` or the Cake console `./bin/cake.php` there's immediately an exception:

> **type:** Aura\Intl\Exception
>
> **message:** "Package 'cake' with locale 'en_US' is not registered."

I had a look online and I found [one other person encountering the same issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cake-php/MiJMZX7utQo/w8ftu0MAEgAJ) but their eventual solution was just to disable xdebug, which isn't what I want. I'm wondering how having xdebug enabled can cause this issue, and how I can work around it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Worth noting I tried disabling caching by putting the following in my bootstrap.php

```
// Disable all cache reads, and cache writes.
Cache::disable();
```

This didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error too. I found that it somehow was related to VS Code, since I had no problems debugging in Sublime.

After a bit of trial and error I found that adding:

```
"ignore": [
    "**/vendor/**/*.php"
]
```

to my `launch.json` fixed the problem. I'm not quite sure about this magic behind, but now I am able to move on.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug